# How to hide redirect url link in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

I need to hide the end of this URL:

```
www.xxx.com/zaloguj/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elefantti.iq.pl%2F
```

I want to get this:

```
www.xxx.com/zaloguj
```

How can I achive this effect in wordpress?

Comment: Sorry my link dosent copy. 

I have log in button in wordpress site . When i click log in site is redirect and url look like this http://www.xxx.pl/zaloguj/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elefantti.iq.pl%2F

What i what to know is to how can i achive effect like this for Url Link

http://www.xxx.pl/zaloguj/

Comment: Any one can help me?